# Adding RedirectAttributes parameter causes "Model has no value for key" exception in Spring MVC controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring MVC controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tournament/{id}/set-format", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSetTournamentFormat(Model model,
                                         @ModelAttribute("formatSettings") FormatSettings formatSettings,
                                         @AuthenticationPrincipal UserAccount currentUser,
                                         @PathVariable("id") int tournamentId,
                                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
        throws TournamentAccessDenied, TournamentNotFoundException, ModifyngOngoingTournamentException {

    Tournament currentTournament = tournamentManagementService.findTournamentById(tournamentId);

    tournamentManagementService.setTournamentFormat(currentTournament, formatSettings);

    model.addAttribute("tournamentId", currentTournament.getId());

    return "redirect:/tournament/{tournamentId}/setup";
}
```

When I click submit button in corresponding form I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'tournamentId'
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
[...]
```

Everything works well when I remove redirectAttributes parameter but I need it to add flash attributes in case of any error. I try to understand why URL template doesn't work. It is also ok when (without removing redirectAttributes) I just use:

```
return "redirect:/tournament/" + currentTournament.getId() + "/setup";
```

My Spring version is 4.1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point providing both `Model` and `RedirectAttributes` parameters in your handler method. `RedirectAttributes` can do everything `Model` can do and more.

The actual issue is the following:

1. The Spring MVC request handling process uses a single `ModelAndViewContainer` which holds a reference to a `Model`.
2. To provide a `Model` argument to your handler method, Spring MVC returns the default `Model` in the `ModelAndViewContainer`.
3. To provide a `RedirectAttributes` argument to your handle method, Spring MVC creates a new instance and uses it to overwrite the default `ModelAndViewContainer` `Model`.
4. When you add the attribute to the `Model`, the `ModelAndViewContainer` won't have access to it and therefore neither will component that process the `redirect:` view name.

Choose one. You don't need both.

```
redirectAttributes.addAttribute("tournamentId", currentTournament.getId());
```

Comment: In case anyone is as stupid as I am, you will get the same error if you have a typo in the redirect path variable name, for example `@PathVariable Integer identity` and `return "redirect:/path/custom/{id}`